An example of an organic compound with an axis of improper rotation, but no inversion center
I'm currently learning elements of symmetry to understand optical activity in organic compounds. I have been told that compounds with an inversion center ($i$), and compounds with an alternate axis of symmetry ($S_n$) must have a way to ensure superimposability with its "mirror" molecule, and are hence achiral.
I have been offered limited examples on the last one, $S_n$, and the only two that I know of, that have an alternate axis are namely $\alpha$-truxillic acid ($S_2$) and trans-1,3-dimethylcyclobutane. However, I have noticed that both of these examples have a center of symmetry too. And due to some crude intuition I have in my mind, I'm unable to tell myself that both aren't equivalent symmetry elements. Can anyone explain the fundamental difference? Also, is there a counterexample? (i.e. a molecule(s) with alternate axis of symmetry but no inversion center?
[I have attempted to search for counterexamples and explanations on the internet, but everyone just gives the definitions and then shift the spotlight to plane of symmetry and center of symmetry. I have also seemingly failed to find any relevant queries here on StackExchange.]

If you mean molecules of point groups with an S$n$ (rotation reflection) operation and no inversion operation then there are several point groups to choose from, tetrahedral T$d$ for example so an example is methane but also $\mathrm{S_4,S_8,D{4d},D{3h},C_{5h},C_{3h}}$. You can find examples  of molecules in this site  https://molecule-viewer.com

Also, $S_2$ is the same as center of symmetry.

Ivan Neretin, I believe this was my mistake, I repeatedly took examples of compounds with an S2 axis of symmetry. My foolish brain couldn't think of methane itself, which has an S4 axis  I apologise for not giving sufficient thought to my question before posting. Should I take this question down, now that I have realised how trivial the counterexample is?

You can easily create molecules in the $\mathrm{S}{4}$ point group with substituted cyclobutanes. Put the same groups, except alternate both $(R)$ and $(S)$ and the side of substitution on adjacent carbons of the cyclobutane. Since the substitution diametrically opposite on the cyclobutane is the same, there is no inversion center. This immediately also suggests that $\mathrm{S}{2n}$ where $n$ is not divisible by 2 doesn't work since the substitution opposite the ring will be inverted. For example, cyclohexanes substituted in this pattern have an inversion center.

Cyclooctatetraene in its most stable $D_{2d}$ tub conformation has an improper fourfold rotation axis but no center of symmetry.
